# how to make 2 separate substrings from strsplit in R

Tags: r

I am struggling to get 2 separate strings from splitting a string using `strsplit` in R. I appreciate this is probably a very simple request but I can't seem to find an answer.

I have a string called `x` which looks like this:

```
"1.23e+05,1.3e+05"
```

I tried to split it using this code:

```
str_split <- strsplit(x,split= ',', fixed=TRUE)
```

which seem produces a list of length 1, with a character of : `"1.23e+05" "1.3e+05"`

However when I try and subset this using `str_split[1]` it just returns the whole thing.

What is the simplest solution to get 2 substrings from this results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the use of `unlist()` and save in a vector:

```
#Data
x <- "1.23e+05,1.3e+05"
#Split
str_split <- unlist(strsplit(x,split= ',', fixed=TRUE))
#Output
str_split[1]
str_split[2]
```

Output:

```
str_split[1]
[1] "1.23e+05"
str_split[2]
[1] "1.3e+05"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you subset the list to access the first element contained within the list, you should get the behavior you expect:

```
str_split <- strsplit("1.23e+05,1.3e+05", split= ',', fixed=TRUE)
str_split[[1]]

[1] "1.23e+05" "1.3e+05"
```

The output is a character vector with two items in it.  I don't see the need or use of having two separate variables here.  But, in case you wanted that, you could just use:

```
exp1 <- str_split[[1]][1]
exp2 <- str_split[[1]][2]
```